# Why is the HttpContextHolder needed when implementing the HttpContextAccessor based on AsyncLocal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I don't understand why they use `HttpContextHolder` as in this code for `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext`:

```
public HttpContext? HttpContext
{
    get
    {
        return _httpContextCurrent.Value?.Context;
    }
    set
    {
        var holder = _httpContextCurrent.Value;
        if (holder != null)
        {
            // Clear current HttpContext trapped in the AsyncLocals, as its done.
            holder.Context = null;
        }

        if (value != null)
        {
            // Use an object indirection to hold the HttpContext in the AsyncLocal,
            // so it can be cleared in all ExecutionContexts when its cleared.
            _httpContextCurrent.Value = new HttpContextHolder { Context = value };
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't we use it in a simpler way like this?

```
public HttpContext? HttpContext
{
    get
    {
        //the Value references an instance of HttpContext directly
        //instead of via a holder
        return _httpContextCurrent.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        _httpContextCurrent.Value = value;            
    }
}
```

Is there any memory-leak issue involved in here affecting how we code it?

**PS**: the full source code for [HttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ea008c80d5cc63de7f90ddfd6823b7b006251ff/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs)

Comment: You can find the original PR here https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/1066

Comment: @davidfowl thank you, could you add more explanation (related to the original code with `TraceIdentifier` involved) in an answer so that I can understand more as well as accept it (will be useful for others as well). 
Really I think in the context of using `IHttpContextAccessor`, there is just one instance of `HttpContext` to be involved. Isn't that `AsyncLocal` behind the scene will separate the instances among requests (consuming their own thread). Looks like `AsyncLocal` flows the reference (value) through contexts and all those can't be auto-collected once the outer-most scope exits?

Comment: @davidfowl BTW, is that "holder" a good pattern to follow when using `AsyncLocal` in every case? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a good pattern when the lifetime of the async local is decoupled from the async local itself.

Comment: @davidfowl sorry but what you said is still vague to me. As I understand we usually use an `AsyncLocal` as a static (and readonly) field (so its lifetime is usually coupled with the application lifetime) but I don't understand what you meant by `the async local itself`? do you mean about its `Value`? If so the `Value`'s lifetime is of course usually decoupled from the static readonly field of `AsyncLocal`. So it's almost always the case we need to follow the *holder* pattern as implemented for `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: This is what that pattern is trying to solve "When somebody accesses the current value after the request is over" the current value return? We want it to return null.

Comment: @davidfowl do you mean that someone can still access that value even when the request is over? It's kind of a very rare case, I mean almost the time we work with (access) a request when it's still in the scope (not over yet). For me in some scenarios even if that value can be accessed when the request is over, it's not very important. The only thing I care about here is if the memory allocated for that value can be freed OK (sooner or later), in other words, there should not be any memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with how `AsyncLocal<>` is implemented.
`AsyncLocal` maintains a sepparate value for each `ExecutionContext`, so whenever a new `ExecutionContext` is created from the current execution context, it gets a **copy** of the current `AsyncLocal<>` variable.

If `AsyncLocal<HttpContext?>` was used here, that `HttpContext` would be copied in all the new `ExecutionContext`'s. So, when you would set

```
_httpContextCurrent.Value = null;
```

it would only update the copy in the current `ExecutionContext`, leaving the other copies untouched and also leading to potential memory leaks.

However, if the `HttpContextHolder` is used, the `HttpContextHolder` object is copied to each new `ExecutionContext`, but all these holders keep the same reference to the same `HttpContext` inside, so when you set

```
holder.Context = null;
```

it basically nullifies and clears the memory for all the `ExecutionContext`'s.